# kableExtra - color of stripe

Tags: r, colors, knitr, kable, kableextra

It seems like this question has been asked in multiple places and has been answered, but it does not work for me. I would like to alternate color of `kable`. Color alternation works but shading is only of very light color. I would like to make it darker. Here is my example:

````
```{r test}
library(kableExtra)
my_df <- data.frame("col_1" = c(1,2,3), "col_2" = c(1,2,3))

knitr::kable(my_df)%>%
  kable_styling("striped", stripe_color="red")

```
````

Here is output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help for `kable_styling` indicates `stripe_color` works only with latex output:

> stripe_color   LaTeX option allowing users to pick a different color for
> their strip lines. This option is not available in HTML.

One way to get alternating color backgrounds with html output is with `row_spec` (though there may be better ways):

```
library(kableExtra)

my_df <- data.frame("col_1" = c(1,2,3), "col_2" = c(1,2,3))

kable(my_df)%>%
  row_spec(seq(1,nrow(my_df),2), background="red")
```

Here's the output with a lighter background color and bootstrap styling for nicer-looking output:

```
kable(my_df)%>%
  row_spec(seq(1,nrow(my_df),2), background="#FF000020") %>% 
  kable_styling(full_width=FALSE)
```

[image]